# Disabling long press in MonkeyRunner

Tags: android, monkeyrunner

I am using the MonkeyRunner Drag functionality, which always does long presses instead of Drag events. Is it possible to disable long press? Is there any other solution for this?

Comment: You can return false in your onLongPress event, so that longPress will not work

Answer (score 0):

You can try to override the `onLongClick()` method and leave it empty for not performing any action.

Comment: i am giving the drag command from the PC to the android device.Actually i am not touching the source code of the android app. So i cant proceed this.. Some where in the stack overflow i have found that we need to disable the long press  like that

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the user "is a monkey" with `android.app.ActivityManager.isUserAMonkey()`

So just disable your OnLongClickListener if the user is a monkey.

```
if (ActivityManager.isUserAMonkey()){
    myView.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: i am giving the drag command from the PC to the android device.Actually i am not touching the source code of the android app. So i cant proceed this.. Some where in the stack overflow i have found that we need to disable the long press like that – user2160741 45 secs ago edit i am giving the drag command from the PC to the android device.Actually i am not touching the source code of the android app. So i cant proceed this.. Some where in the stack overflow i have found that we need to disable the long press like that

Comment: AFAIK, no, there's no way to disable long presses via settings.

Comment: then y the monkey runner drag command is not working properly..WE have given coordinates with '1' step and '0' ms delay.. even though its taking as a long press

Comment: Are you testing a custom view?